# Why I can't use std::string in C++ template?

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is my simple program on function template.
When I compile this I get a compilation error saying - "ambiguity",
I am unable to understand what is the problem here.  The compiler should translate 3 definitions one for `int`, `double` and `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>

int max(T a, T b)
{
   return a < b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::cout<<max(5,2)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<max(2.14, 2.34)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<max(static_cast<std::string>("ads"), static_cast<std::string>("yasdsf"))<<std::endl;
   std::string ts = "hello";
   std::string ts1 = "hi";
   int x = ts < ts1;
   std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<max(static_cast<double>(2.243) , 23.23424)<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This is the compilation error -

```
error: call of overloaded ‘max(std::string, std::string)’ is ambiguous
   14 |    std::cout<<max(static_cast<std::string>("ads"), static_cast<std::string>("yasdsf"))<<std::endl;
      |                                                                                      ^
simple_function_template.cpp:5:5: note: candidate: ‘int max(T, T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
    5 | int max(T a, T b)
```

Comment: Your function conflicts with `std::max`, which is found via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Rename it to something else, or call using `(max)(a, b)` or `::max(a, b)`.

Comment: or use `::max()`.

Comment: Found a dupe. Different names, but the same problem.